# I wanna run my SOSL to search for a string obtained by function parameter

Tags: apex, sosl

I wanna search for a particular string obtained by my function parameter in Contact & Lead FirstName & LastName fields..
The difficulty is  how to compose a SOQL statement for that,as I am getting problem with the following piece of code:
[image]

However when I pass a string,it works perfect,it is not just allowing the parameter obtained to be passed in the query..

[image: Code that works]

Am I doing something wrong?
Please let me know...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate out there somewhere, but the answer is you have to *bind* to the query:

```
List<SObject[]> searchList = [FIND :param IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(FirstName, LastName), Lead(FirstName, LastName)];
```

Do not use the quote (') or the ({}) characters. You can bind directly to a variable.

Comment: @ShobhitSaxena You're welcome!

Comment: what if I want to make "Contact, Lead(FirstName, LastName)" this dynamic. I'm trying to create list of string, but it is not working

Comment: @Nehal You can't bind field/object names. You would use dynamic SOSL, as mentioned in the other answer. Did you check the documentation? You might want to ask a new question if you're stuck. We'll be glad to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

I am not very familiar with SOSL but i think It can be done using [dynamic SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_sosl.htm).

for eg.

```
String searchquery='FIND\'Edge*\'IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(id,name),Contact, Lead'; 
List<List<SObject>>searchList=search.query(searchquery);
```

Similarly you can do like this:

```
String searchquery='Find '+param+ 'Other part of query'
```

Comment: what if I want to make other part of query "Contact, Lead" also dynamic. I'm trying to create list of string, but it is not working